# Can a composite foreign key reference a composite primary key and not have all the values NOT match (Oracle)? And in the same table?

Tags: oracle12c

This is an existing table in Production.  Adding a new row with a unique primary key causes failure to enable the foreign key with 'parent does not exist' but the data is there. PK does not prevent insert so I know it's unique.

ALTER TABLE tableA ADD (CONSTRAINT tableA_PK
PRIMARY KEY
(SEGMENT, STEP)
USING INDEX tableA.tableA_PK
ENABLE VALIDATE;

ALTER TABLE tableA ADD (
CONSTRAINT tableA_FK
FOREIGN KEY (SEGMENT, PREDECESSOR_STEP)
REFERENCES tableA (SEGMENT, STEP)
ENABLE VALIDATE);

Note:  PREDECESSOR_STEP will never be = to STEP.  SEGMENT, PREDECESSOR_STEP each have their own non-unique index:

SEGMENT - unique index
STEP - unique index
STEP - also has a non-unique index
PREDECESSOR_STEP - non-unique index

A primary key values look like:

AEM     CAL_NVR_ID

The foreign key values:

AEM     CAL_NVR

When I try to insert a row with these exact values I am getting : 'parent does not exist' when enabling the fk constraint.

Comment: A foreign key _must_ match what it points to, by definition. You can't have a partial match and still call it a foreign key constraint.

Comment: pmdba - This is what I thought but that scenario is running in production and I don't understand how.

Comment: Is it possible that the constraint is disabled in Production? That's the only explanation I can think of.

Comment: All constraints, triggers and indexes are enabled in production.  I have no idea what to do with this.

Comment: Have you opened a ticket with Oracle Support? This feels like a possible bug to me. I found references on My Oracle Support to past bugs (supposedly all fixed now) where FKs were not enforced under certain conditions.

Comment: I have not.  The table with the disabled FK was in test and missing a parent row.  When I added the row back I enabled it no problem.  I still don't understand this relationship though.  It creates a hierarchy of batch jobs run through a scheduler and the PK and FK and indexes are as described above.  Thank you for responding.